# Is It Possible To Write Username Of Editor To Cell In Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting frustrated with the ever-evolving capabilities/ restrictions of Google Script.

I would like to accomplish the seemingly simple task of writing a timestamp and the editor's username to an adjacent cell whenever they edit a cell within a column.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
/**
 * Get current user's name, by accessing their contacts.
 *
 * @returns {String} First name (GivenName) if available,
 *                   else FullName, or login ID (userName)
 *                   if record not found in contacts.
 */
function getOwnName(){
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var self = ContactsApp.getContact(email);

  // If user has themselves in their contacts, return their name
  if (self) {
    // Prefer given name, if that's available
    var name = self.getGivenName();
    // But we will settle for the full name
    if (!name) 
      name = self.getFullName();
    return name;
  }
  // If they don't have themselves in Contacts, return the bald userName.
  else {
    var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
    return userName;
  }
}
```

However, getEffectiveUser only grabs my username, as opposed to the current editor. getActiveUser returns nothing.

The alternative is not pretty. I saw some example where the current user would select their email from a list of all editors when they opened the spreadsheet. The email would be stored somewhere on a scratch sheet and somehow pasted into the cell when the user would make an edit, though the email storage and retrieval were left out of the example.
As a horrible and incredibly slow/ inefficient hack I insert the timestamp, then popup a page with a listbox and button, grab the usernames from a cell-range, and when the editor selects their name it should paste the value into the adjacent cell. However that seems to randomly run into authorization issues for some as yet undetermined reason, not to mention being insanely slow:

```
function show() {
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var specialSheet = doc.getSheetByName("ADDL. INFO");
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Select Name').setWidth(150).setHeight(150);
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   var lb = app.createListBox(true).setId('myId').setName('myLbName');

   // add items to ListBox
   lb.setVisibleItemCount(4);

    // Getting a known named range from spreadsheet object.
  empLocRange = specialSheet.getRange("A28:A32");
  //.getRangeByName('EmployeeLocations');
  empLocs = empLocRange.getValues();
  empLocs.sort()

    for (i=0; i < empLocs.length; ++i) {    
      empLoc = empLocs[i][0].toString().trim();
      if (!(empLoc=='')) {
        lb.addItem(empLoc);
      }
    }
   panel.add(lb);
   var button = app.createButton('Select');
   var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('click').addCallbackElement(panel);
   button.addClickHandler(handler);
   panel.add(button);
   app.add(panel);
   doc.show(app);
 }


 function click(eventInfo) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   // get values of ListBox
   var value = eventInfo.parameter.myLbName;
   // multi select box returns a comma separated string
   var n = value.split(',');
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var p = r.getRow();
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);    
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  nextCell.setValue(value);
   app.close();
   return app;
 }
```

I read that publishing the script as a stand-alone app you can access the current username but it does not seem like that would be the correct solution. I thought I may be able to install this script for each user as a solution, but it does not seem to operate in that manner.

Any assistance or would be greatly appreciated.

Edit.
Forgot to include the function that calls this:

```
function timestamp() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var p = r.getRow();
    if( r.getColumn() == 14 ) //checks the column
    { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);      
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      //s.setActiveSelection(p + "15");
      show();
      //SpecialonOpen();
      //nextCell = r.offset(0,2);
    //nextCell.setValue(getOwnName());
    }
}
```

I have the above timestamp function set to trigger on edit - timestamp, from spreadsheet, on edit.

UPDATE:
I have been banging my head against this some more.
This is the result, though with odd, unexplained behavior.
My current scripts:

```
function getOwnName(){

  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  //Browser.msgBox("getOwnName");
  //var self = ContactsApp.getContact(email);
  var self = false; 

  // If user has themselves in their contacts, return their name
  if (self) {
    // Prefer given name, if that's available
    var name = self.getGivenName();
    // But we will settle for the full name
    if (!name) 
    {
      name = self.getFullName();
    }
    //Browser.msgBox(name);
    return name;
  }
  // If they don't have themselves in Contacts, return the bald userName.
  else {
    var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
    //Browser.msgBox(userName);
    return userName;
  }
}

function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var p = r.getRow();
    if( r.getColumn() == 14 ) //checks the column
    { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);      
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      //Browser.msgBox("hey!");
      //s.setActiveSelection(p + "15");
      //show();
      //SpecialonOpen();
      var nCell = r.offset(0,2);
      //Browser.msgBox("olah:" + getOwnName());
    nCell.setValue(getOwnName());
    }
}
```

I commented out `//var self = ContactsApp.getContact(email);` as it seemed to be crashing the script.
After doing so I went to one of my users and asked them to test. Still no username written to the cell. I told him to open up the script and execute the function with the play-button. This popped up an authorization message. He agreed to authorize the script and upon returning to the spreadsheet his name was successfully inserted into the cell.
However, the script still will not write his user name to the cell when triggered by onEdit. So I really have no idea what is going on with GS. We are both on the same domain.

Comment: Is the function getOwnName also triggered by onEdit?

Comment: It was originally, you can see that I commented that line out (//nextCell.setValue(getOwnName());). That was my initial attempt, however, getEffectiveUser would only return my username, or the document owner's and when I switched to the getActiveUser function, it would return nothing. I would prefer to get that function working and returning the username of the editor who triggered the onEdit trigger. However, that seems to no longer be possible, unless the function is a stand-alone-app. Or something....

Comment: I have a cell that is set to a certain value from a dropdown: completed, pending and cancelled. When that is changed I want to set the adjacent cell to the current dateTime and the cell next to that to the editor's username. Other things I have tried is moving the active cell (the username cell originally contained a dropdown populated by a range of cells), but apparently that functionality was removed as well. If there is some way to trigger the dropdown upon edit that would probably be the most ideal/ actually able to be implemented at this point.

Comment: The problem is that installable triggers run as the author of the trigger... and getactiveUser works only in the context of a domain ... is it your case?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the issues I've been running into. However, I really do not understand why. All of the editors of this document are on the same domain (not gmail/ google).

Comment: According to this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/5D23Os_NIAc  
The getEffectiveUser() function should return something. Is there some method of individual users authorizing the script? I haven't seen anything pop up for anybody except myself when I first created the script.

Comment: I had one of my users go in and run and subsequently authorize the script from the script project page. I added additional information to the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact possible, and the right way to do this is the
        [Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())

Google states in the docs:

> If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger

Though we have this working. It is not clear to me why this works, but as soon as I added a menu entry calling the same function as onEdit, and after closing and opening the Spreadsheet, I got an authorization request, from then on it worked.

Comment: I've managed to get it working for me, the author, but not for other users. I've been unable to determine what triggers the authorization request.

Comment: I managed to get it working for all of our domain users. 
The authorization request is triggered as soon as you try to execute code which need authorization. For example clicking the Run button in the Script editor.However

Comment: However authorizing from the script editor did not work for me. But as soon as I added a menu in the document and executed the function from there, I got an authorization request in the document. From then on also the onEdit function works, for all users. I did this as the documents owner though.