# How to specify the spreadsheet in which a google api code should work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My google sheets document has multiple sheets (tabs). How do I specify the spreadsheet in which code should work?
I am using the last code from the post below to collect the date and user who changes a particular cell, but the code works for all spreadsheets (tabs) in my document.

[Is It Possible To Write Username Of Editor To Cell In Google Docs Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916035/is-it-possible-to-write-username-of-editor-to-cell-in-google-docs-spreadsheet)

I would like it to work on just one spreadsheet: "Test"

I tried this but to no avail:

**var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");**

```
    function getOwnName(){

  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  //Browser.msgBox("getOwnName");
  //var self = ContactsApp.getContact(email);
  var self = false; 

  // If user has themselves in their contacts, return their name
  if (self) {
    // Prefer given name, if that's available
    var name = self.getGivenName();
    // But we will settle for the full name
    if (!name) 
    {
      name = self.getFullName();
    }
    //Browser.msgBox(name);
    return name;
  }
  // If they don't have themselves in Contacts, return the bald userName.
  else {
    var userName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    //Browser.msgBox(userName);
    return userName;
  }
}

function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 14 ) //checks the column
    { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);      
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      //Browser.msgBox("hey!");
      //s.setActiveSelection(p + "15");
      //show();
      //SpecialonOpen();
      var nCell = r.offset(0,2);
      //Browser.msgBox("olah:" + getOwnName());
    nCell.setValue(getOwnName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The active cell is the one that is being edited, no matter what the sheet is.

If you want to stick to `getActiveCell()`, you need to implement an if statement verifying if you are in the right sheet:

```
function onEdit() {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()=="Test")
  {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 14 ) //checks the column
    { 
      ...
```

**A different elegant solution would be to work with [e.range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()=="Test")
  {
   var r = e.range;
   if( r.getColumn() == 14 ) //checks the column
    { 
     ...
```